# Android: Possible to create ProgressDialog without using Thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

I have a ListActivity which loads data from a database during onCreate(). Is it possible to show a ProgressDialog without using a thread? Using a thread seems to disable the ListActivity's onListItemClick method. But maybe I'm doing something wrong. I'm also doing a lazy load of items in my listactivity, so the list loads 10 items at a time using onScroll.

Any help or direction is appreciated:)

Answer (score 0):

`ProgressDialog` is always running on `UI thread`, so you don't need any additional thread to create it. Threads are used for long-running operations, that can last for more than 5 seconds, cause blocking the UI thread will trigger the ANR error. If you're sure your loading process won't ever take 5 seconds, you can do it right on `UI thread` with showing a `ProgressDialog` (or a `ProgressBar`, which I feel is better, cause it doesn't prevent your users from working with your application). If the loading can last for some longer, you should think about implementing a separate thread to handle this process. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think I can be sure that it won't take longer than 5 seconds. But when I tried to put the loading of items into a seperate thread, the onListItemClick wouldn't execute once I scrolled through my list. Do you perhaps know the reason for this?

Comment: @ashv, it shouldn't be this way, seems like you've made a mistake somewhere. General advice is to use AsyncTask, it's a classic method of resolving this kind of problems in Android.

Comment: Ah okay. I'm new at android development, so probably you're right:)
Do you know of any tutorials I can have a look at for AsyncTask?

Comment: @ashv, here's a good post, you should take a look at it:
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Comment: Please do *not* use the UI thread for *any* I/O operations whether local or network. With millions of Android devices out there even the smallest data transfer _will_ encounter the degenerate case where this takes a long time and _will_ cause an ANR.